# Apply a Function to a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, function, dataframe, dictionary, url

I have an ELIF function to determine whether or not a website exists. The elif works, but is incredibly slow. I'd like to create a dictionary to apply the ELIF function to the list of URLs I have. Ideally I'm looking to get the outputs into a new table listing the URL and the result from the function.

I'm creating a dictionary for the potential outputs outlined in the elif statement posted below

```
check = {401:'web site exists, permission needed', 404:'web site does not exist'}





for row in df['sp_online']:
    r = requests.head(row)
    if r.status_code == 401:
        print ('web site exists, permission needed')
    elif r.status_code == 404:
        print('web site does  not exist')
else:
        print('other')
```

How can I get the results of the confirmation function to show each url's result as a new column in the dataframe?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Apologies, I'll update the post. I don't know how to apply the confirmation function to the dataframe I have to show the results as a new column for each row in the original dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your should try a Thread or Multiprocessing approach. Instead of requesting one site at a time, you can pool n websites and wait for their responses. With `ThreadPool` you can achieve this with a few extra lines. Hope this is of use to you!

```
import requests
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

list_sites = ['https://www.wikipedia.org/', 'https://youtube.com', 'https://my-site-that-does-not-exist.com.does.not']

def get_site_status(site):
    try:
        response = requests.get(site)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("Connection refused")
        return 1
    if response.status_code == 401:
        print('web site exists, permission needed')
    elif response.status_code == 404:
        print('web site does  not exist')
    else:
        print('other')
    return 0

pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)

results = pool.map_async(get_site_status, list_sites)

print('Results: {}'.format(results.get()))
```

Comment: Thanks, Rafael. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'status': [401, 404, 500]})
check = {401:'web site exists, permission needed', 404:'web site does not exist'}
print(df['status'].map(check))
```

prints

```
0    web site exists, permission needed
1               web site does not exist
2                                   NaN
Name: status, dtype: object
```

Assign to a new column in the normal way

```
df['new_col'] = df['status'].map(check)
```